Forest plot univariable in R (finalfit | or_plot)
I want to create a forest plot of the OR using univariable regression. Preferably with an outcome like the or_plot() from the finalfit package. However, this does not support univariable analysis. Can someone help me with an alternative? Or a method to combine the univariable outcome of finalfit(dependent, explanatory)?
Finalfit example using finalfit
Multivariable
The last figure creates a forest plot, but for multivariable only. I would like such a plot for univariable.
Hopefully someone can help me with this question.
I tried creating a ggplot from the finalfit results table, but this is not in the desired format and styling as I would prefer.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Yes, you can do this.
library(finalfit)
library(gridExtra)

explanatory = c("age.factor", "sex.factor", "obstruct.factor", "perfor.factor")
dependent = "mort_5yr"

fit_uni = colon_s %>% 
  glmuni(dependent, explanatory)

p_uni = colon_s %>%
  or_plot(dependent, explanatory, suffix = " (univariable)", remove_ref = TRUE, 
    glmfit = fit_uni)
p_multi = colon_s %>%
  or_plot(dependent, explanatory, suffix = " (multivariable)", remove_ref = TRUE)

grid.arrange(p_uni, p_multi)



Thank you for your help Ewen! This is exactly what I was looking for.
